# Brackets in URL causes all manners of madness

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile version of a website using jQuery mobile, but have found the vast majority of the built in functionality is broken.

The problem arises from my URLs, they look like this:

http://www.mysite.com/testurl/(S(3wlciqrhccimwx133y2sivxb))/Home/Logon.aspx

^^^
The bit in brackets is different for each session.

Any use of the back button, or ajax page loading causes this error:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: data-url='/testurl/(S(0f2xpaxk5131rsm1rkmantws])/Home/Index.aspx')

I really, really need help with this, I've bodged my way around most of the problems, but if I could just get the core functionality to work, my life would be a lot easier.

Cheers!

Comment: Seems its an open & unfixed issue, https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1468 you will need to change the mobile js to escape the parens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Alex K's advice, here's edited the edited jquerymobile.js file that allows brackets in the urls - hope it helps someone else:

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzlad/bWUsa/